# synchronize two webform select options

Tags: webforms

In my webform page I have two select options components:

Item number:
20 | 20 ,
35 | 35 ,
40 | 40

Price List:
100 | 100 ,
200 | 200 ,
300 | 300

I need these two select options components synchronized. If one selects Item number (35) the price list also moves to (200).

Is there any module available to do that, or how can I get the synchronization of the two select options.

Comment: Quick hint: I think the easiest way to do it is through JavaScript. Use `.change()` event to change value in the other option set. If noone replies and if you don't know to do this on your own, I'll post a solution later.

Comment: Thank you in advance. I don't know. I am a drupal user not programmer, but I have a xampp server and drupal in my computer, so I can try the codes and put it to the real server.

Comment: That might be harder for you to do then. Why don't you just merge everything in one list? E.g. "Select item" and for options have: "20|20 - price: 100, 35|35 - price: 200, 40|40 - price: 300"? That would be the easiest solution and you won't have to write code.

Comment: The latest version of the webform module has same-page conditionals. You may be able to twist that around enough to do what you want. However, I suspect that, in the end, you are going to just have to write some custom JavaScript.

Comment: @Topsitemaker, If I can merge it looks ok. The list is long list, generated from Webform Views Select (https://www.drupal.org/node/2483637). How to merge the fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not need to synchronize, but combine (merge) them in one list. 
In [Webform Views Select](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/mrconnerton/1373760)  I can also combine by using Rewrite Results,

field "Item Number", exclude from display

field "Price List", 
Rewrite Result:
[value] - price [value_1]

Then I can get in a single select option list: 
20 - price 100
35 - price 200
40 - price 300